# Sql table data conversion from decimal to binary with multiple records

Tags: sql, dynamic, qsqlquery

Sql table data conversion from decimal to binary with multiple records

table details

```
PK_No   Model1  Model2
PK-01     3       4
PK-02     5       6
```

Need output

```
PK_No   Model1  Model2
PK-01     1       0
PK-01     1       0   
PK-01     0       0
PK-01     0       1
PK-02     0       0
PK-02     1       0
PK-02     0       1
PK-02     1       1
```

I HAVE USED CROSS APPLY and also tried through Substring and split.
but its becoming heavy to handle.

I just need to convert 100 rows of decimal data into 400 rows of binary data

Comment: You need a sequence/id column too.

Comment: Please can you update your question to explain the logic you are using to generate the output from the source?

Comment: And what is wrong in cross apply version?  It [works fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/B9zkqsKZ). Please show your query